# Can't start QjackCtl

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS.

When I use an audio WineHQ app, with pulseaudio, I can't start QjackCtl.

That app gives me the following error messages:

"Jack audio server could not be started. Sorry. Please see the messages window."

And... the messages window tells me:

```
01:36:29.899 Registro iniciado --- sáb. sept. 23 01:36:29 2017 ---
01:36:29.964 Reiniciar estadísticas.
01:36:29.972 Cambios en las conexiones ALSA.
01:36:29.975 D-BUS: Disponible (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
01:36:30.041 D-BUS: El servidor JACK no puede iniciarse. Disculpa
Cannot connect to server socket err = No existe el archivo o el directorio
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No existe el archivo o el directorio
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
01:36:30.193 Cambió el gráfico de conexiones ALSA.
Sat Sep 23 01:36:29 2017: Starting jack server...
Sat Sep 23 01:36:29 2017: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Sat Sep 23 01:36:29 2017: self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Sat Sep 23 01:36:30 2017: ERROR: cannot register object path "/org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0": A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
Sat Sep 23 01:36:30 2017: ERROR: Failed to acquire device name : Audio0 error : A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
Sat Sep 23 01:36:30 2017: ERROR: Audio device hw:0 cannot be acquired...
Sat Sep 23 01:36:30 2017: ERROR: Cannot initialize driver
Sat Sep 23 01:36:30 2017: ERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1
Sat Sep 23 01:36:30 2017: ERROR: Failed to open server
Sat Sep 23 01:36:31 2017: Saving settings to "/home/control01/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
01:36:32.139 No puede conectarse al servidor JACK como cliente. - La operación global falló. - No puede conectarse al servidor. Por favor revise la ventana de mensajes para mas información.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No existe el archivo o el directorio
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
01:36:33.119 Escaneo del patchbay ALSA activo...
```

I'm no a programmer, so...

What's wrong here???

Comment: The localised error messages are difficult to understand. You can make most programs print English messages by prefixing the command with `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX free`. Works the same for graphical applications. With super-user privileges you need `sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt ...` or `gksudo env LC_MESSAGES=POSIX synaptic` (for graphical applications).

Comment: what settings did you use in QjackCtl?
is D-Bus enabled for switching audio devices between Pulseaudio and JACK ?

Comment: JACK says D-Bus isn't available at all when I start the Wine PulseAudio app.

Comment: do not understand, what is Wine PulseAudio app? Studio16.04 has D-Bus enabled in qjackctl by default. sounds like you are using something other than GUI package qjackctl to start JACK sound server